# Update SQL with Aliased tables still returns "table is ambiguous" error

Tags: sql, sql-update, table-alias

I am trying to run the below update but running into the "table is ambiguous" error.

```
UPDATE dbo.cg
SET cg.column = gId.ID
FROM    dbo.a
        INNER JOIN dbo.cg as cId ON cId.[a] = dbo.a.[c]
        INNER JOIN dbo.cg as gId ON gId.[a] = dbo.a.[b];
```

The table dbo.a contains data to update a value in cg based on a relationship to same table against a value in a different column.  It is a self-referencing hierarchy.

As you can see, everything is aliased so I am a bit confused why this won't run.

Many thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: `SET cg.column = ....`, well, you have 2 `cg` tables in your query, that's why you are getting that message

Comment: Even though I have aliased the other two?  I have looked about how would you suggest I alias the SET even further than I have done so.

Answer (score 18):

In SQL Server, you should use the *alias* in the `update`, not the table.  In addition, you have no alias called `cg`.  So something like this:

```
UPDATE cId
SET column = gId.ID
FROM dbo.a a INNER JOIN
     dbo.cg cId
     ON cId.[a] = a.[c] INNER JOIN
     dbo.cg gId
     ON gId.[a] = a.[b];
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response Gordon.  I have tried that I must say to get round this but I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

Not to worry, solved it by luck.

I inner joined the table to itself in desperation ...

```
UPDATE dbo.cg
SET cg.column = gId.ID
FROM    dbo.a
        INNER JOIN dbo.cg as cId ON cId.[a] = dbo.a.[c]
        INNER JOIN dbo.cg as gId ON gId.[a] = dbo.a.[b]
        INNER JOIN cg ON cId.[a] = cg.[a];
```

If anyone could explain why that has worked, I would really appreciate understanding the MS SQL logic underneath.

Comment: I stumbled on the same issue today, joining on itself made the error go away and the update works. Really weird IMO